# In NestJs, how do I resolve circular dependencies between types?

Tags: nestjs, circular-dependency

I have two services in two different modules that both need to call each other, but ran into circular dependency issues.

After searching and finding dozens of answers recommending `forwardRef()`, I tried that:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AntsService {
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => BatsService)) private batsService: BatsService) {}
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class BatsService {
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => AntsService)) private antsService: AntsService) {}
}
```

However, I was still getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AntsService' before initialization
```

None of the answers I saw addressed this second error that shows up after adding forwardRef(). What can I do to fix this?

I tried using the `ForwardReference` (eg. `ForwardReference<AntsService>`) class that comes in `@nestjs/common`, which only gave me access to injected properties of the service, but not access to it's functions.